# Fread: ferror on pty without data?

Tags: c, posix, pty

I have two processes communicating via a pty, nonblocking. Problem is that the `fread()` on the master fails when there is no data available to process.

How can I ignore the "no reader/data present" case when reading from the unconnected file descriptor on the master side? I suspect there is some flag for `open()` or `fcntl()` which I skipped during reading?

```
// initialization:
int pty_fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
int rc = grantpt(pty_fd);
rc = unlockpt(pty_fd);
fcntl(pty_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
fd_read = fdopen(pty_fd, "r");

// now, trying to read will fail if no data is present:
char buf[100];
int count = sizeof(buf);
size_t bytesRead = fread(buf, sizeof(char), count, fd_read);
if ((bytesRead == 0) && (ferror(fd_read)) {
    printf("fail...\n");
}
```

Sure, I can ignore the return value of `ferror()`, but I suppose this is not the right way to use this function.

Ah, one thing: I found the [POLLHUP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3490197/4658481) trick on stackoverflowz. It works but is racy and hence not suitable for my case...

Greetings

Comment: What do you expect/want fread to return in such case?

Comment: Zero, as it does. But I would expect `ferror()` to not be true...

Comment: Requesting some bytes and receiving less bytes *is* either an eof or an error condition, by definition. You need to examine errno to see what kind of error it is, and decide how to handle it.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use stdio with ptys or other special fd types that have transient EOF or error conditions when you actually want to treat those conditions as transient. There are ways to make it work, but working directly with file descriptors usually makes more sense.

Comment: @n.m. Is it an error even when I said O_NONBLOCK? How can I distinguish between "no bytes present" (I'm Ok with that) and "the world is on fire" (should probably call exit now...)?

Comment: I would guess it is an error by definition, the definition being "whenever the underlying POSIX I/O layer sets errno" (probably EAGAIN in this case).

Comment: ha, somehow I did not notice that errno is set anyways, even by fread... stupid me...