# Efficiently wait for pty slave to be open

Tags: python, linux, pty

I am working on a program that opens a master/slave pair to communicate between them. I need to wait until some process connects to the slave and starts sending data.

I have used the trick described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3490197/1451794) to tell if the port is open or not by setting the HUP signal. I can check for the port to be open, but when I try to read I get `read failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error`. Doing select does not block. I have tried epoll in the hope edge polling might work both when setting and unsetting a flag, but it works just the same.

Is there any way to block waiting for the HUP flag to become unset, which will happen if the port is open?

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use PTYs for the inter-process communication ?

Comment: Yes. My program is supposed to talk to other programs that usually talk to serial devices.